# Table creation with php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i'm trying to do a table with php which takes the data from my database and build's the table im html but despite my while loop , only the 1st row is getting into the table. If i change the while loop before the

```
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'";
```

I get all of them but in 3 tables.

What's wrong with the code ?

```
<?php
    require 'connect.php';

    $query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM fornecedor");

    echo "Fornecedores";

    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='2'";

    echo "<tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>NIF</td>
            <td>Cidade</td>
            <td>Rua</td>
            <td>NrPorta</td>
            <td>Website</td>
            <td>email</td>
        </tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Nome"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["NIF"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Cidade"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Rua"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["NrPorta"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Website"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Email"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        };

 ?>
```

Comment: Just as a side note, you're mixing procedural and object oriented `mysqli` commands.

Comment: Yeah, i'm mixing up a bit but all seams to be working ? Where is my mistake in here , the fetch_array or the query ?

Comment: No mistake really, as long as it works. To make it consistent you could simply `$query->fetch_array()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array($query);`. Either should work though. Just better to be consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `echo "</table>";` out of the `while` loop-

```
....
while(){
   .....
   // don't close the table tag here
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I need to wait 10 minutes before that ! You were just to quick to solve it :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For each row you are adding the closing `</table>` tag which should not be like that.
`echo "</table>";` code must be out of the `while` loop. It must be written once only.